# How to extract object properties that are stored in an array in jQuery and place them into another variable

Tags: jquery, arrays, object, properties, insert

I am trying to extract object properties from an array of objects and store them in a variable that will be added to an HTML object. What is currently happening when I execute this just creating the  without the content from the icon variable. In the console it logs icon as [object object]. Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CoderLevel1/ftc0mn4f/) and here is my code.

```
var dHtml = "";

var fieldTypes = [ 
    {"label":"Text", "icon":"abc-icon", "cls":"text-class"},
    {"label":"Date", "icon":"calendar-icon", "cls":"date-class"},
    {"label":"Radio", "icon":"radio-icon", "cls":"radio-class"},
    {"label":"Checkbox", "icon":"checkbox-icon", "cls":"checkbox-class"},
    {"label":"Selector", "icon":"dropdown-icon", "cls":"selector-class"},
    {"label":"Telephone", "icon":"telephone-icon", "cls":"telephone-class"}
];

var icon = jQuery.each(fieldTypes, function(l,ll) {
    console.log(ll.icon);
});

for (i = 0; i < fieldTypes.length; i++) {

    dHtml += "<div style='padding-top:6px; padding-right:5px;' id='drag'><div id='" + icon + "'></div></div>";
};

jQuery('#pop').html(dHtml);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to store it in a separate variable. Simply iterate `fieldTypes` using `JQuery` and append value of field `icon`into `dHtml`.

```
$.each(fieldTypes, function(i, ll){
   dHtml += "<div style='padding-top:6px; padding-right:5px;' id='drag'><div id='" + ll.icon + "'></div></div>";
});
```

In other way you can create an array `icons` to store values of all icon and later you can use it.

Sample code:

```
var icons = [];

$.each(fieldTypes, function(l,ll) {
    icons.push(ll.icon);
});
```

Running sample code that prints all icons.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

var dHtml = "";

var icons = [];

var fieldTypes = [ 
    {"label":"Text", "icon":"abc-icon", "cls":"text-class"},
    {"label":"Date", "icon":"calendar-icon", "cls":"date-class"},
    {"label":"Radio", "icon":"radio-icon", "cls":"radio-class"},
    {"label":"Checkbox", "icon":"checkbox-icon", "cls":"checkbox-class"},
    {"label":"Selector", "icon":"dropdown-icon", "cls":"selector-class"},
    {"label":"Telephone", "icon":"telephone-icon", "cls":"telephone-class"}
];

$.each(fieldTypes, function(l,ll) {
    icons.push(ll.icon);
});


$.each(icons, function(i, icon){
   dHtml += "<div style='padding-top:6px; padding-right:5px;' id='drag'><div id='" + icon + "'>"+icon+"</div></div>";
});

document.write(dHtml);
  
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I am relatively new to jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly refactored version of your code, that in my opinion is much cleaner:

```
var fieldTypes = [ 
    {"label":"Text", "icon":"abc-icon", "cls":"text-class"},
    {"label":"Date", "icon":"calendar-icon", "cls":"date-class"},
    {"label":"Radio", "icon":"radio-icon", "cls":"radio-class"},
    {"label":"Checkbox", "icon":"checkbox-icon", "cls":"checkbox-class"},
    {"label":"Selector", "icon":"dropdown-icon", "cls":"selector-class"},
    {"label":"Telephone", "icon":"telephone-icon", "cls":"telephone-class"}
];

$("#pop").empty();

$.each(fieldTypes, function(index, fieldType) {
    var innerDiv = $("<div>", { id: fieldType.icon });
    var outerDiv = $("<div>", { id: "drag", padding: "6px 5px 0 0" });
    $("#pop").append(outerDiv.append(innerDiv));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm new to jQuery so I basically live at jquery.com

Comment: Yeah, that is a fantastic resource. And good luck learning jQuery, it is a very useful tool!